# NSData initWithContentsOfFile is empty

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsdata

I created a simple test project to parse XML.  I created a .plist file in my app for this test.  I copy it over to the documentsDirectory.  I can see the file gets copied over.  When I try to initialize it into a NSData object for the NSXMLParser, I get:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 4.)
```

This tells me that the file doesn't exist.  I checked that the NSData is not nil, and that the fileExistsAtPath, and both checked out ok.  I'm kind of stuck on what to try next.  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];

    NSString *path = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testList.plist"];

    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
if (data == nil) {
    NSLog(@"yes nil");
}
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded  
{ 
    // First, test for existence. 
    BOOL success; 
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSError *error; 

    NSString *writableDBPath = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testList.plist"]; 
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath]; 
    if (success) return; 
    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location. 
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testList.plist"]; 
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error]; 
    if (!success) { 
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]); 
    }
}

- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    return documentsDirectory;
}

#pragma mark - NSXMLParserDelegate
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"hg19Packet0.bin"]) {
        NSLog(@"first");
    }
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError {
    NSLog(@"%@", [parseError localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: Log out your data to verify it has the right contents: `NSLog("data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at your sample plist from a text editor? If you're saving it as a binary property list, it won't be parseable using NSXMLParser (I believe). You can use NSPropertyListSerialization to parse it, however.